# execute shell step skipped completely in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I can't seem to run a build execute shell step in Jenkins.  I've worked with Hudson in the past on windows and I was able to create shell/batch steps without a problem but I seem to be be missing something here.

It's a fresh jenkins install and I go to "add build step", "execute shell" and enter "echo hi" in the command.  I run the build and when I look in the console output, nothing happens.

I've also tried executing a test.sh file which also just echoes hi.  I've tested this in both a linux install and an os X installed Jenkins server.

What am I missing in the configuration to run a shell script?

The console output shows that the shell script steps were skipped completely

```
Started by user admin
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Could you add the output from the console here?

Comment: the console output shows nothing except for the bare bones..Started by user admin
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Which version of Jenkins do you have? The last good version that I can attest to is 1.447. If you're not using that one, could you try with it. Also, could you add `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` before `echo hi` on your "Execute Shell" for the linux system and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the reply earlier.  I'll try out your advice when I get back to the office on Monday!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Jenkins is not being able to redirect the output from the system. What version of Java are you using? If you're using OpenJDK, could you try with Sun Java/Sun JDK?

First test to try to check if anything is executing at all: add the following to your "Execute Shell"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "HELLO WORLD" > /tmp/testfile
```

Run this and check if there is a /tmp/testfile in on your Linux system, and if it contains the `HELLO WORLD` text, it means your script is in fact executing.

Which version of Jenkins do you have?

The last good version that I can attest to (last one I know works well at least for us) is 1.447. If you're not using that one, would you be able to try with it?

Also, could you add `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` before `echo hi` on your "Execute Shell" for the Linux system and see if that works.

Also, try running a script using `source /path/to/script` and see if that works. The script should contain `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, just to see if that makes a difference.

Note: none of this should be required, but is helpful just to get more information on what's going on. Couldn't fit all this into a comment. I'll update my answer based on your answers to the above, or delete if I can't get anything..

Comment: So it looks like it was a silly thing, I had selected a "multi-configuration project" in the job creation screen and for that reason it wouldn't execute any shell scripts until I had defined the configuration matrix.  Once I created some configurations, it ran the shell scripts in their respective configuration workspaces.

Comment: lol, it generally tends to be the smallest things. glad you sorted it out!

Comment: what about in window system?

Comment: @SurendraJnawali what of it? You should be able to try the same steps, except for your shell, whichever you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this here for posterity.

I had a Jenkins project configured with Maven running `clean test` and a execute shell in the pre steps. The logs from Maven where not coming through and the script was not executing. Once I unchecked `Build modules in parallel` under the Maven build options my logs and scripts started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its in a location where Jenkins can see it, check permissions.

Comment: I did check permissions, put it in the home workspace... I also just did echo hi, which is not a file.