# how to make jenkins run a python script that executes a build?

Tags: python, hudson, jenkins

Learning Jenkins, and trying to get it to build a project for which my build script is written in python.

```
./build.py -i
```

I've tried using the 'Execute script' and 'Execute Python script'.  The script first line is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Jenkins doesn't complain about either attempt, it just seems to ignore the setting, declaring the build successful as soon as the code is checked out.

I've read a few old mail lists that hint that I'll have to write a bash script (build.sh) and have it call the python script.  I hope that's not the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use an "Execute shell" build step and specify `/path/to/build.py -i`

I'm guessing that the current directory when the build job runs isn't what you're expecting.  Jenkins has a built-in environment variable WORKSPACE that is set to the root of the build's workspace, so assuming that the Python script is at the root of your checked out code, `$WORKSPACE/build.py` should also work.

Comment: This was part of my problem. I found the main part of the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851886/execute-shell-step-skipped-completely-in-jenkins) - mainly "I had selected a 'multi-configuration project' in the job creation screen and for that reason it wouldn't execute any shell scripts until I had defined the configuration matrix."  Unfortunate that it's a silent failure.  Once that was changed, I could see the script fail to execute, and fixed the path from there.  It needed $WORKSPACE/trunk/<script>, because of the svn checkout directory.